# How to load the IBOutlets from NIB in the the init method?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nib, iboutlet

I need access to the IBOutlets in my initWithNibName method of my UIViewController, but they are all nil as they haven't been instantiated yet. Is there a way to instantiate them? I have read that is not safe to call -loadView as it will cause memory leaks. So please tell me if there is any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Generaly it's not possible, your try to access things that don't even exist in this moment. Why wouldn't you use viewWillAppear() method in this controller? I think it's all that you need. Give us sample of code or something more to work on.